# error: cannot find symbol class 'of' (Android Studio: Can't Resolve Symbol 'of')

Tags: android

[Can't resolve symbol 'of'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJuYS.png) << Image

Does anyone know why Android Studio is giving me the error 'error: cannot find symbol class 'of'?

I'm trying to use the 'ModelViewProviders.of(Fragment fragment)'

Answer (score 0):

You should use ViewModelProviders.of(Fragment f). Please check.

Comment: Maybe androidx, I guess

Answer (score 0):

`ViewModelProviders.of()` is a static method, therefore you should remove the `new` keyword:

```
mWordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WordViewModel.class)
```

Note that as per [the `ViewModelProviders` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders), this class is deprecated and if you're using the latest version of Fragments, you'd instead use `new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class)`